# Recording video and audio with AVAssetWriter in Swift

Tags: swift, audio-recording, video-recording, avassetwriter

Im trying to add the devices microphone audio to a video recording from the devices camera. The video is filtered with a CIFilter and works as expected. My problem is the mic audio is not attached to the video once saved.

I have tried setting the audio settings manually like this

```
let audioSettings : [String : Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 64000
]
```

but using the recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter method seems like the correct approach as the video recording works with the recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter method.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this or point me in the right direction?

My code so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    lazy var cameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
        return AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
    }()
    
    lazy var micDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
        return AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
    }()
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var outputURL: URL!
    var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    var filterObject = FilterObject()
    var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    var assetWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?
    var fileName = ""
    var recordingState = RecordingState.idle
    var time: Double = 0
    
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    let context = CIContext()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCameraDevice()
        setupAudioDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setUpAuthStatus()
    }
    
    @IBAction func recordPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch recordingState {
        case .idle:
            recordingState = .start
        case .capturing:
            recordingState = .end
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func setUpAuthStatus() {
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) != .authorized {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video, completionHandler: { (authorized) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if authorized {
                        self.setupInputOutput()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.audio) != .authorized {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.audio, completionHandler: { (authorized) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if authorized {
                        self.setupInputOutput()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    func setupCameraDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
        
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == .back {
                cameraDevice = device
            }
        }
    }
    
    func setupAudioDevice() {
        let audioDeviceDisoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInMicrophone], mediaType: .audio, position: .unspecified)
        let devices = audioDeviceDisoverySession.devices
        micDevice = devices[0]
    }
    
    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            guard let cameraDevice = cameraDevice else { return }
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
            
            guard let micDevice = micDevice else { return }
            let micDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: micDevice)
            
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
            
            if captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            }
            
            if captureSession.canAddInput(micDeviceInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(micDeviceInput)
            }
            
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.apple.sample.capturepipeline.video", attributes: [])
            
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
                captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            }
            
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput) {
                audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
                captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
            }
            
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            captureSession.startRunning()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {return}
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
        
        guard let name = filterObject.name else {return}
        let effect = FilterType.genericFilter(name: name, cameraImage: cameraImage)
        effect.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        TableData.setFilterValues(withFilterName: name, effect: effect, values: [value1, value2])
        
        guard let outputImage = effect.outputImage else { return }
        context.render(outputImage, to: imageBuffer)
        
        guard let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: cameraImage.extent) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            self.imageView.image = filteredImage
        }
        
        let timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer).seconds
        
        switch recordingState {
        case .start:
            fileName = UUID().uuidString
            let videoPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).mov")
            let writer = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoPath, fileType: .mov)
            
            let videoSettings = videoOutput.recommendedVideoSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov)
            let videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
            videoInput.mediaTimeScale = CMTimeScale(bitPattern: 600)
            videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            
            let audioSettings = audioOutput.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .m4a)
            let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings as? [String : Any])
            audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            
            //videoInput.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
            let pixelAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)
            
            if writer.canAdd(videoInput) {
                writer.add(videoInput)
            }
            
            if writer.canAdd(audioInput) {
                writer.add(audioInput)
            }
            
            writer.startWriting()
            writer.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
            
            assetWriter = writer
            assetWriterInput = videoInput
            pixelBufferAdaptor = pixelAdapter
            recordingState = .capturing
            time = timestamp
        case .capturing:
            if assetWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
                let newTime = CMTime(seconds: timestamp - time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600))
                pixelBufferAdaptor?.append(imageBuffer, withPresentationTime: newTime)
            }
            break
        case .end:
            guard assetWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true, assetWriter!.status != .failed else { break }
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).mov")
            assetWriterInput?.markAsFinished()
            assetWriter?.finishWriting { [weak self] in
                self?.recordingState = .idle
                self?.assetWriter = nil
                self?.assetWriterInput = nil
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
                    self?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to find the answer?

Comment: @czater I did not find a solution.  GPUImage2 does achieve this pretty well if your willing to use it.

Comment: @Jeff did you happen to find a solve or create a workaround? i have a similar setup (believe we may have followed the same online example) but too cannot output any audio... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714369/avassetwriter-output-does-not-capture-audio

Answer (score 0):

Your audio settings do not look correct.  The AVSampleRateKey should come from the number of samples from the description of the first audio sample that comes in.  Your value of 44100 should be set as the value for the AVEncoderBitRateKey and that should maybe be set to AVEncoderBitRateKey: Int(48_000)

To get the number of sample first call

```
let fmt = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) 
let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(fmt!)
```

and then the sample rate will be asbd?.pointee.mSampleRate and then that should be set as the AVSampleRateKey value in the audio settings (I think)